# Optimizing NGINX Configuration for video serving

Tags: nginx

Hello I have set up my VPS for media delivery (mp4 videos) to my main site, this VPS is only used for this purpose, my website is hosted on a different VPS. I think the speed is a bit slow but not a big problem currently but I want to make sure that it is a good configuration since I do not have good experience with NGINX and found this configuration online here it is:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  6;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    # add proxy caches
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/mycache keys_zone=mycache:70m;
    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    access_log off;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        root /usr/local/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            alias /usr/local/nginx/html;
        }

        location /rtc {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8088/janus;
        }

        location /rtcapp {
            # enable thread pools for livestream
            aio threads=default;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8188;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location ~ \.flv$ {
            # enable thread pool
            aio threads=default;
            flv;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /home/my_videos/;
            mp4;
            mp4_buffer_size     1M;
            mp4_max_buffer_size 3M;
            # enable thread bool
            aio threads=default;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'example.com';
            valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return   403;
            }
            # enable caching for mp4 videos
            proxy_cache mycache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 300s;
            proxy_cache_lock on;

            # enable nginx slicing
            slice              1m;
            proxy_cache_key    $host$uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
            proxy_set_header   Range $slice_range;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            # Immediately forward requests to the origin if we are filling the cache
            proxy_cache_lock_timeout 0s;

            # Set the 'age' to a value larger than the expected fill time
            proxy_cache_lock_age 200s;

            proxy_cache_use_stale updating;

        }

}
}
```

my server specs are:

```
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
16 GB RAM
400Mbit/s Port
400 GB SSD
```

is there any thing I can edit to make it perform better or is it already optimized?

Comment: Why do you think it is slow?

Comment: I think it is slow on startup but then the speed is okay, meaning when I first load the page it takes some time for the video to start and also when skipping to different parts of the video it takes some time to load that too otherwise the speed is okay